# While using sax parser for parsing an xml with '&' as a part of data, the parser breaks

Tags: android, xml-parsing, saxparser

I am using SAX parser for XML parsing when my XML contains tag like

```
<ServicePath>../Master/WebForm1.aspx?IsFirst=1&amp;&amp;</ServicePath>

 <ServicePath>../FieldBook/ExportFieldBookData.aspx</ServicePath>
```

I am getting only "&" and "x" respectively in my database.How to solve this problem of parsing using SAX parser....

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I could solve this by storing the data in the string builder and not string. Try this if you are using a string.

```
    @Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)throws SAXException 
{
    currentElement = false;


    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
    {

            header.add(sb);


    }
    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description"))
    {

            desc.add(sb);

    }

    }



     public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)throws SAXException
{
    super.characters(ch, start, length);




    Sb = new StringBuffer();
    Sb.append(ch, start, length);


}
```

the header and the desc are my arrayists and the sb is my stringbuilder.

Comment: can you post how can use string builder to store my tag value. In my case I have stored it in MAP and then inserted in database.